# I want to change the stroke color of svg icon when click on it in angular 2 or 4?

Tags: angular

it is not wroking can anyone give solution for it??

```
this is svg icon code.
```

```html
<svg id="Home" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52.28 43.49">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2.27px;}
    </style></defs>
  <title>Home</title>
  <polygon id="home-2" data-name="home" class="cls-1" points="26.18 1.31 1.17 15.82 1.16 16.72 8.26 16.72 8.26 42.36 21 42.36 21 31.16 31.36 31.16 31.36 42.36 44.1 42.36 44.1 16.72 51.11 16.72 51.09 15.76 26.18 1.31"/>
</svg>
```

this code for image calling in another html class.

```
<a id="HomeFabricButton" [ngStyle]="{'background': status, 'border-radius':ChangeRadius}">
    <img src="../../../images/Home.svg" title="Home" [ngStyle] = "{'clas-1.stroke':changeColor}" (click)="ChangeStatus()" />
</a>
```

Comment: With jquery, can you not get the svg?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass styling inside svg without directly placing svg content on the page then the only way is to use [svg parameters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/#PassingValuesViaURLParameters)
But there are no browsers supporting this so you would have to include a [polyfill](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/param.js)

PS: I have tried it and it works but make sure you read all notices like this on the page I referenced:

> Note that these examples are emulated by a Javascript prototype. It should work in Opera, Firefox, and Safari, and maybe others (Chrome? Plugins?). The script may be used as is, and is released under a CC license, but it is not intended as production code. Content authors are encouraged to experiment with this code, and to comment to the SVG WG at www-svg@w3.org with suggestions and critiques of the specification based on experience.